# How can i optimze the below condition in android/kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, logic

I have a function like this and it returns the ENUM data.

```
            if (shouldShowCTA) {
                if (progress) {
                    when (type) {
                        TYPE1 -> TYPE1_PROGRESS
                        TYPE2 -> TYPE2_PROGRESS
                        else -> null
                    }
                } else if (completed) {
                    when (type) {
                        TYPE1 -> TYPE1_COMPLETED
                        TYPE2 -> TYPE2_COMPLETED
                        else -> null
                    }
                } else {
                    null
                }
            } else {
                null
            }
```

Here I have a repeated code of When condition. How can I combine all the if and else if at one condition?

Comment: Does the returned enum need to have all permutations of combinations with the first enum type? That seems hard to work with. Without seeing the code in context, I can't be sure, but I suggest making the enum simply have values PROGRESS and COMPLETED.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it like this:

```
if (shouldShowCTA) {
   when {
      type == TYPE1 && progress -> TYPE1_PROGRESS
      type == TYPE2 && progress -> TYPE2_PROGRESS
      type == TYPE1 && completed -> TYPE1_COMPLETED
      type == TYPE2 && completed -> TYPE2_COMPLETED
      else -> null
   }
} else {
    null
}
```

Just a note that this way you lose `when`'s exhaustiveness, since it's not `when(value) {` syntax but `when {`

Comment: You could throw in `!shouldShowCTA -> null` at the top to keep all the logic in the `when`, it's another case really

Comment: @cactustictacs Yeah, you could do that, but then it would make `when` contents order-dependent, and I wanted to avoid that for this case

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!shouldShowCTA)
   return null

if(progress)
    return when (type) {
        Type1 -> {}
        Type2 -> {}
        else -> null
   }

if(completed)
   return when (type) {
        Type1 -> {}
        Type2 -> {}
        else -> null
   }

return null
```

Comment: how can I return TYPE1_COMPLETED, TYPE1_PROGRESS etc

Comment: I forgot that part, I already corrected it.